# how to retrive the values from my sql table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli

I want to retrieve (stratageeks,HCL,IMIMobile) value from the table where `user_id=wordpress` how it possible

This is my Table

```
       id   user_id     company_name    number_save
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
       1    wordpress   Stratageeks     1
       2    Manju       Stratageeks     1
       3    Manju       Wipro           2
       4    wordpress   HCL             2
       5    wordpress   IMIMobiles      3
```

Comment: google, you would get huge no. of examples for this question. I would suggest go step by step for learning the SQL instead jumping to a particular portion.

Comment: send me the example link

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html,
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm,
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT company_name FROM table WHERE user_id='wordpress'
```

You should consider learning basic SQL if you plan on doing this in the future.

If you want distinct results, use:

```
SELECT distinct company_name FROM table WHERE user_id='wordpress'
```

Comment: BUT it will select only first rows company_name means stratageeks

Comment: @user2826209 This query would return all three of your desired names: `Stratageeks, HCL, IMIMobiles`